# value is not available on the view when creating custom directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am trying to create custom directive and am using scope values in 'ng-repeat', everything is working fine except the view, i mean, on the view(html) {{item.value}} is not printing but the same is printing on the JS code(in console) inside the controller.

Any help on this where am missing?

```
<html ng-app="test">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="test">    

        <div style="border: 1px solid #000000; height: 30px;width: 100px" ng-repeat="item in items" my-directive on-drag-start="handleDrop(item.id,item.value)"><span style="color:red">{{item.value}} </span></div> //{{item.value}} here value is not printing 

    </body>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('test', []);

        app.directive('myDirective', function () {
            return {
                scope: {
                    onDragStart: '&'
                },
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                    scope.onDragStart();

                }
            }
        });

        app.controller('test', function ($scope) {

            console.log("inside the Controller");

            $scope.items = [{id: 1, value: "Test1"}, {id: 2, value: "TEst2"}];

            $scope.handleDrop = function (elementId, file) {
                console.log("Reseult from view", elementId, file);
            }


        });

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template in your directive and pass each ng-repeat item. I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TgyxDZFqKzupWf8uEYHZ?p=preview).

First pass the item in your HTML into your directive

```
ng-repeat="item in items" my-directive data="item"
```

Then you expect the data in your directives scope

```
data: '=',
```

And finally your template

```
template: '<span style="color:red" ng-bind="data.value"> </span>',
```

For more complex templates and better separation, you can use templateUrl.

Comment: For your information, i do not want to use 'template' as it is my need. Could you please help me the same without template?

Comment: I updated the Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/TgyxDZFqKzupWf8uEYHZ?p=preview. Templates are just a nice way to separate. You can also use the scope-variables directly in your html, if that feels better for you. Directives with scope: {} create a private scope that cant access the ng-repeat items.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Scope that is inside the red Span is the scope of the directive and not that of the controller/ngRepeat. So the ngRepeat value is not getting reflected in the span. One way is to assign the `item` to another attribute `item-cache` and inserting it into the directives scope:

```
scope: {
   onDragStart: '&',
   item: '=itemCache'
}
```

That would transfer what ever the current item into the directives scope and your `{{item.value}}` should work as is.